# Adjusting for age or age^2 in logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, anova

I'm doing a study where I'm comparing patients who are alive+event-free after 10 years of follow-up ('healthy survivors') compared to those who are not, using logistic regression to describe determinants of these healthy survivors.

It makes sense that age at baseline is a major determinant that decides how big your odds are for being a healthy survivor, and I want to make sure that all determinants are adjusted for age.

For example, I want to look at systolic blood pressure. This is my output.

```
> model<- glm(healthysurv ~ systbp+age+gender, family= "binomial", data=data)
> summary(model)

Call:
glm(formula = healthysurv ~ systbp + age + gender, family = "binomial", data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.1595  -1.0334  -0.6239   1.0547   1.9183  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  4.312298   0.402830  10.705  < 2e-16 ***
systbo      -0.006105   0.002379  -2.567 0.010267 *  
age         -0.066295   0.005148 -12.877  < 2e-16 ***
gender       0.404866   0.112192   3.609 0.000308 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 2747.5  on 1981  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2502.1  on 1978  degrees of freedom
AIC: 2510.1

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

I think adjusting for age^2 might be better, as I think the effect of age may be more important in the upper range than in the lower range, so I've also constructed this model and compared it using `anova`.

```
> model2 <- glm(healthysurv ~ systbp+pol(age,2)+gender, family= "binomial", data=data)
> summary(model2)

Call:
glm(formula = healthysurv ~ systbp + pol(age, 2) + gender, 
family = "binomial", data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.7634  -1.0799  -0.4986   1.0001   2.2235  

Coefficients:
                             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                -2.3680827  1.3433791  -1.763 0.077937 .  
systbp                     -0.0053212  0.0024058  -2.212 0.026977 *  
pol(age, 2)age              0.1643460  0.0449712   3.654 0.000258 ***
pol(age, 2)age^2           -0.0019779  0.0003875  -5.104 3.32e-07 ***
gender                      0.4367176  0.1135007   3.848 0.000119 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 2747.5  on 1981  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2477.0  on 1977  degrees of freedom
AIC: 2487

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4


> anova(model,model2,test="Chisq")

Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: healthysurv ~ systbp + age + gender
Model 2: healthysurv ~ systbp + pol(age, 2) + gender
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
1      1978     2502.1                          
2      1977     2477.0  1   25.112 5.409e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Question:
Is `anova` the correct way to test this for `glm`? If it is, it would mean that age^2 is indeed better to use for adjustment since the p-value for the anova is <0.05, right?
And am I even correct in assuming that age^2 is a good way to adjust my model?

Additional question: Could I use the AICs of the models in this case?

Comment: Before you consider a polynomial, you should probably consider interactions. Typically, e.g., you'd expect interactions between age and gender effects.

Comment: @Roland: I have also considered interaction, however in this specific example of blood pressure (`glm(healthysurv ~ systbp*age+gender, family= "binomial", data=data)`), the interaction term systbp*age was not significant with a p-value of .26. So I'm thinking age is a confounder rather than an effect modifier for the relation between systolic blood pressure and healthy survival.

Comment: @BenBolker: I'm not familiar with the concept of overdispersion. Would you by any chance happen to know a good source to make myself familiar with the subject? I'd be much obliged.

Comment: @tamarV I think Roland is likely right about the presence of  interaction. The problem is that you may not have a singly type of interaction in this instance. Being younger might be positive, but if that young person has higher systolic BP it might offset, being older might be negative, but the negatives mediated by low systolic BP. In this case the model and summary statistics from it are less likely to provide insight about the next step than your understanding of the system, subjects and relationship you are evaluating...but I agree that the jump to polynomial is premature.

Comment: @sconfluentus: Right. Could I use e.g. splines to visualize the relationship to see whether it seems to be logarithmic or quadratic etc.?

Comment: Start simple,have you tried plotting graphs, scatter plots, and looking at clusters to see if there are multiple relationships? Having a visual sense of the data might help you choose a modeling method.